# Perl 5.32 define statement syntax

Tags: perl

I just setup a new dev environment and went from Centos 7 (perl 5.16 v16) to RHEL 8.5 (perl 5.26.3). With that said, I cannot figure out the new syntax for the define statement in this old sub. Any help with this last line would really be appreciated. I just can't get it to work:

```
my $flags_loop = db()->retrieveSet(table => "flags",order=>["flag"],dir=>'DESC');
my $outflags;

foreach my $flag (@$flags_loop) {
    my $flagsize = db()->count(
        table => "songflag", 
        where => { flagid => $flag->{flagid} } );
    $flag->{flagsize} = $flagsize;
    push (@$outflags, $flag);
}

# in case no flags yet defined
# 5.26 incompatible
if (!defined(@$outflags)) { $outflags=[]; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `defined` on non-scalar things never quite worked how anyone thought, or at least people DWIM-ed a different meaning than `defined`'s original intent.

`defined` on arrays (and some other things) was deprecated in Perl 5.005, but as with many deprecations, it didn't actually go away. Eventually, v5.16 (the version you were using previously) got serious about it (no, really this time!) and added a deprecation warning that you get even without enabling warnings. The warning tells you want to do:

```
$ perl5.16.3 -e 'defined(@ARGV)'
defined(@array) is deprecated at -e line 1.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

There's no new syntax: just old syntax you don't use at all. Perl has been pretty good at deprecation warnings for several versions now because the developers are pretty serious about removing all the things that have been listed for removal for a couple decades.

Using `diagnostics` gives a longer explanations of the error, showing you what to do if you want to check that the array is empty.

```
defined(@array) is deprecated at -e line 1 (#1)
    (D deprecated) defined() is not usually useful on arrays because it
    checks for an undefined scalar value.  If you want to see if the
    array is empty, just use if (@array) { # not empty } for example.

    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

Even then, this feature was in Perl until v5.22. The warning tells you what to do:

```
$ perl5.32.0 -e 'defined(@ARGV)'
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I get an error message similar to the following:

```
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

When I change:

```
if (!defined(@$outflags)) { $outflags=[]; }
```

to:

```
if (!(@$outflags)) { $outflags=[]; }
```

The error goes away.

See also: [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined)

Answer (score 1):

Remove that line and replace

```perl
my $outflags;
```

with

```perl
my $outflags = [ ];
```

Explanation follows.

---

Checking if an array is defined makes no sense.

Usually, when someone uses that construct, they want to check if the array is empty. (That's not quite what it does.) If that were the case here, you would replace

```perl
if (!defined(@$outflags)) { ... }
```

with

```perl
if (!@$outflags)) { ... }
```

The error message even suggests this might be the case. But it's not. `@$outflags` is never empty, so you're not trying to check if it's empty.

You're actually trying to ensure that `$outflags` is always a reference to an array. Without that line, the `$outflags` would be `undef` if no flags are found.

So, specifically, you are trying to check if `$outflags` is `undef`. As such, you should replace

```perl
if (!defined(@$outflags)) { ... }
```

with

```perl
if (!defined($outflags)) { ... }
```

---

That said, there's a simpler approach. Since `$outflags` is either a reference or `undef`, we could also check for truth rather than definedness. That means that

```perl
if (!defined($outflags)) { $outflags=[]; }
```

can be replaced with

```perl
if (!$outflags) { $outflags=[]; }
```

But we could simply use

```perl
$outflags //= [];
```

But that's not the simplest approach! We could avoid that line entirely by initializing `$outflags` from the start!

```perl
my $outflags = [];
```

Comment: `my $outflags = []` for the win and reducing special cases and checks!